# Connection between IIS and client browser

Tags: iis, browser, connection, client

What is the connection between IIS and client browser? How do they communicate?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is how web servers and browsers communicate. If you want a lower level protocol it's TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

IIS is a web server. The client browser makes HTTP connections to a server machine, which IIS handles and responds to.

Answer (score 0):

Just most other browser / client combinations: The HTTP protocol over TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

They communicate using the HTTP protocol, which runs on top of the TCP/IP protocol.

If you wanted more specific information, then please ask a more specific question.

Comment: HTTP is not based on TCP/IP: it is transported over.

Comment: What did you think I meant by "based on"?

Comment: @John: I am pretty sure you understand the concepts here... but using the terminology "based on" might be confusing for newbies, that's all.  Coming from a networking background myself, I would say that the terminology used here is confusing at best... but that might only be me. Cheers.

Comment: Coming from a networking background, I decided not to use Networking terminology, to avoid confusing a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Communicate using HTTP which is served normally on TCP which in turn is transported normally over IP (v4, v6) at which point the lower layer protocols vary greatly over the lifetime of the connection to the client e.g. Ethernet, PoS (Packet over SONET/SDH), MPLS etc.).

As with any good Client/Server relationships (network wise speaking in this case), HTTP isn't married to TCP/IP but is usually paired with those for transport purposes.